# How to add class designating seen/unseen items on page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, cookies, local-storage

I want to display an icon that indicates whether or not a visitor to a homepage with a feed of articles has already seen an item or not. So, for example, if you went to the homepage for the first time, all articles in the feed would have an icon that said "NEW". Then, if you navigated away from the homepage and came back, only the new articles since your last visit would have the icon, and all others would have disappeared.

I'm using Rails 4, but it seems like this should be pretty easy to do on the client side with Jquery/javascript using cookies or localStorage.

What's a good solution for this?

For reference, I have a page that displays a feed of articles, each with a unique id as shown below. I'd like to have a class such as `new-item` that would be removed from all seen elements when the page unloads and persist (until the user clears the local storage or the cookie expires). So, in the example below, the first two items would have a "new" tag, whereas the second two were previously seen, and the tag has been hidden.

```
<ol>
  <li class="article" id="article-articleA" data-id="articleA">
    <p class="article-content new-item"><i class="material-icons">star</i>NEW</p>
    ...
  <li>
  <li class="article" id="article-articleB" data-id="articleB">
     <p class="article-content new-item"><i class="material-icons">star</i>NEW</p>
    ...
  <li>
  <li class="article" id="article-articleC" data-id="articleC">
     <p class="article-content" style="display: none;"><i class="material-icons">star</i>NEW</p>
    ...
  <li>
  <li class="article" id="article-articleD" data-id="articleD">
     <p class="article-content" style="display: none;"><i class="material-icons">star</i>NEW</p>
    ...
  <li>
</ol>
```

Comment: "best solution" is a bit subjunctive, it depends on your environment, architecture, performance needs, etc,. If your feed receives lots of request I would go with cookie/javascript solution to spend the client-side computer power...

Comment: You're right on semantics. I edited the question.